# Searching through relationships and date in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I am searching through records that have multiple tags and i only want to show the results with a start_date that has already passed. Its seems to work accept its showing jobs no matter what the start date. The near method is one i have created myself to work out results with a certain distance, the code for that is below

```
public function scopeNear($query, $latitude, $longitude, $distance = 0) {
    $query->addSelect(DB::raw("*, 3959 * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( geolat ) ) * cos( radians( geolng ) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( geolat ) ) ) AS distance"));

    if( $distance > 0 )
        $query->having('distance', '<', $distance);

    return $query->orderBy('distance', 'ASC');
}
```

This function works fine and if i do this

```
$jobs = \App\Job::near($lat, $lng, $distance)->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
```

that works fine as well. But when i use my full query (below) I get results but as i said they haven't been filtered by the start date as expected.

```
$search = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $request->input('keywords'));

$jobs = \App\Job::near($lat, $lng, $distance)->whereHas('skills', function ($query) use ($search) {
        foreach ($search as $keyword) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
        }
    })->orWhereHas('sectors', function ($query) use ($search) {
        foreach ($search as $keyword) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
        }
    })->orWhereHas('title', function ($query) use ($search) {
        foreach ($search as $keyword) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
        }
    })->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
```

Can anyone advise what the problem is? any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`$query->where(...)` returns the modified object instead of manipulating the called instance. You need to continuously update and return the query object, like so:

```
$search = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $request->input('keywords'));

$jobs = \App\Job::near($lat, $lng, $distance)->whereHas('skills', function ($query) use ($search) {
        foreach ($search as $keyword) {
            $query = $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
        }

        return $query;
    })->orWhereHas('sectors', function ($query) use ($search) {
        foreach ($search as $keyword) {
            $query = $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
        }

        return $query;
    })->orWhereHas('title', function ($query) use ($search) {
        foreach ($search as $keyword) {
            $query = $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
        }

        return $query;
    })->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
```